# Angular 15.x ngSrc and ngSrcset issue

Tags: javascript, angular

In my **Angular 15.x** project I'm using **NgOptimizedImage** with **ngSrc** and **ngSrcset** but getting incorrect result according to the documentation.

When I enter:

`<img ngSrc="hello.jpg" ngSrcset="100w, 200w" />`

Documentation says I should get:

`<img src="path/hello.jpg" srcset="path/hello.jpg?w=100 100w, path/hello.jpg?w=200 200w" />`

Instead I get:

`<img src="path/hello.jpg" srcset="path/hello.jpg 100w, path/hello.jpg 200w" />`

So the same image is returned....

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and then saw a warning in the console that hinted at the fix for that:

```
NG02963: The NgOptimizedImage directive (activated on an <img> element with the `ngSrc="../assets/avatar"`) has detected that the `ngSrcset` attribute is present but no image loader is configured (i.e. the default one is being used), which would result in the same image being used for all configured sizes. To fix this, provide a loader or remove the `ngSrcset` attribute from the image. chunk-VDEKOXRT.js:4701:13
```

So configuring a provider in `app.config.ts` like this fixed it for me:

```js
providers: [{
  provide: IMAGE_LOADER,
    useValue: (config: ImageLoaderConfig) => {
      return `${config.src}_${config.width}.png`;
    }
}]
```

For completeness: My HTML:

```html
<img width="6000" height="3200" ngSrc="assets/avatar"
     ngSrcset="600w, 1000w, 1500w, 2000w, 2500w, 3000w, 6000w"
     alt=""
/>
```

And my assets folder:

```
avatar_600.png
avatar_1000.png
avatar_1500.png
avatar_2000.png
avatar_2500.png
avatar_3000.png
avatar_6000.png
```